# Limit switch is good but no heat

Tags: furnace

I am getting a 4 blink indicator saying my limit switch is bad. I tested the switch and it is good. What else could it be?

Comment: What is the make and model of the equipment?

Comment: How did you check the limit? You will have to remove the wires on the limit switch and check for continuity. If there is no resistance across it the switch is bad. Also does the furnace run and trip the limit. Or is the unit stuck in a limit condition and will mot attempt to relight after the furnace cools down and the limit closes?

Answer (score 1):

The limit open error code, simply means that the limit circuit is open. This could be an open limit switch (of which there could be more than one), a loose/disconnected wire, a bad control board, or some other break in the circuit.

Most systems apply 24V to the limit circuit, and if they don't detect ~24V on the other end they throw the error.

Locate the schematic, then trace the circuit to find the break. Without knowing the make and model; or having the schematic, there's not much more help I can provide.